# Python: extend file content while writing in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, try-catch

As a network engineer i have started to learn python some days ago and in the first instance i wanted to write a code which checks a given file for valid and invalid IP addresses then save these into separate files.

The file opening and checking is working as intended but i cannot save the valid and invalid IPs into different txt.

```
import socket


def ip_check():
  with open('ip.txt', 'r') as f:
    while True:
      output = f.readline()
      try:
        socket.inet_aton(output)
        with open ('valid_ip.txt', 'w') as f_val:
          f_val.write(output)
      except socket.error:
        with open ('invalid_ip.txt', 'w') as f_inval:
          f_inval.write(output)
      if not output: break

ip_check()
```

Snippet of IP.txt:

```
82.102.177.55
200.61.155.203
342.2.52.1
125.42.75.52
0.0.0.0
256.34.2.5
71.30.186.48
128.72.94.197
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**: the problem is that you are overwriting your files over and over on each step, you can change mode to `'a'` like:

```
with open ('valid_ip.txt', 'a') as f_val:
    ...
with open ('invalid_ip.txt', 'a') as f_inval:
    ...
```

## Improvements

- We don't need `while True`, `f.readline()` & `break`, because `f` is an instance of [`io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) which is a subclass of [`io.IOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase) and from [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase):

  > **IOBase** (and its subclasses) supports the iterator protocol, meaning that an **IOBase** object can be iterated over yielding the lines in a stream.

  it means that we can directly iterate through `f` and instead of

  ```
  while True:
      output = f.readline()
      ...
      if not output: break
  ```

  write

  ```
  for output in f:
      ...
  ```
- we can collect data at first (e.g. store them in `list`s) and write data into files after.
- we can extract a logic with `try`-`except` into a predicate for checking if given ip is valid like:

  ```
  import socket


  def is_ip_valid(ip):
      try:
          socket.inet_aton(ip)
      except socket.error:
          return False
      else:
          return True
  ```

Finally we can have something like

```
def ip_check():
    valid_ips = []
    invalid_ips = []
    with open('ip.txt', 'r') as f:
        for output in f:
            if is_ip_valid(output):
                valid_ips.append(output)
            else:
                invalid_ips.append(output)
    with open('valid_ip.txt', 'w') as f_val:
        f_val.writelines(valid_ips)
    with open('invalid_ip.txt', 'w') as f_inval:
        f_inval.writelines(invalid_ips)
```

which looks [more readable](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python) to me.

Note that mode is changed to `'w'` again because we're writing results all at once using [`writelines` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines) instead of opening files again and again and writing just a one line each time.

## Further reading

- [`open` function docs](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open).